# Генерация и заполнение Image на View

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, binding

В зависимости от кол-ва выбранных картинок нужно сгенерировать определенное кол-во картинок на странице.
 Что я делаю:
Кидаю картинки в список, потом читаю поочередно и кидаю в другой список.
`ViewModel`

```
private IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> collageimages;
private List<CollageModel> imageList; 
private Thickness temp =  new Thickness (50, 50, 0, 0);

public ImageManipulatorViewModel()
    {
        this.ImageList = new List<CollageModel>();
    }

public List<CollageModel> ImageList
    {
        get { return this.imageList; }
        set
        {
            this.imageList = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("ImageList");
        }
    }

this.collageimages = await OpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
        for (var i = 0; i < collageimages.Count-1; i++)
        {
            var stream = await collageimages[i].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var bitmapImage = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100);
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            this.ImageList.Add(new CollageModel() {CollageImage = bitmapImage, Margins = this.temp});
        }
```

`Model`:

```
public class CollageModel
{
    public Thickness Margins { get; set; }
    public WriteableBitmap CollageImage { get; set; }
}
```

`Binding` на `Xaml`:

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="ImageManipulatorViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<!--...-->

<Canvas 
    Width="Auto"
    Height="1200"
    x:Name="MyCanvas" 
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CollageModel">
              <Image 
                  Source="{x:Bind CollageImage}"
                  Margin="{x:Bind Margins}"
                  Height="100"
                  Width="100">
               </Image>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Но в результате на форме ничего нет. На дебаге заходит в метод нормально, заполняет список

Comment: А `DataContext` установлен?

Comment: @Donil, да, обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `List<CollageModel>` попробуйте `ObservableCollection<CollageModel>`

Comment: Помогло, только почему картинки появляются в столбик? У них `Margin` статичный, по идее они должны быть друг на друге

Comment: Думаю, тут надо в `ItemContainerStyle` лезть.

Comment: Немного погуглил, все примеры для списков и по WPF, может есть какой-то список стилей? Окно Property тоже ничего не подсказывает

Comment: Все стандартные стили лежать здесь `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic\generic.xaml`
Копируете к себе в ресурсы любой, изменяете как хотите и используете.